# Python 3.4.1 Print new line

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, printing, sum

I have quick question that I have been trying to figure out for some time now. I am writing a code that takes inputted number ranges(a high, and a low) and then uses an inputted number to find out if there are multiples of that number within the range. It will then add total the sum of odd and even numbers and add how many there are. I've got everything to calculate correctly but my problem is I can't separate the line "90 75 60 45 30" from the other line "3 even numbers total to 180". I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction? thanks in advance for time and consideration.

The below code returns:

```
Number of high range?: 100

Number of low range?: 20

Multiple to find?: 15

90 75 60 45 30 3 even numbers total to 180

2 odd numbers total to 120
```

Code:

```
def main():


    x = int(input('Number of high range?: '))
    y = int(input('Number of low range?: '))
    z = int(input('Multiple to find?: '))
    show_multiples(x,y,z)

def show_multiples(x,y,z):

    for a in range(x,y,-1):

        if a % z == 0:

            print (a,end=' ')

            even_count = 0
            even_sum = 0
            odd_count = 0
            odd_sum = 0
    for num in range(x,y,-1):
        if num % z == 0 and num % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
            even_sum += num
    for number in range(x,y,-1):
        if number % z == 0 and number % 2 == 1:
            odd_count += 1
            odd_sum += number

    print(even_count,'even numbers total to',even_sum)
    print(odd_count,'odd numbers total to',odd_sum)

main()
```

Comment: Just add a `print()` call before the `for num in range(x,y,-1):` loop.

Comment: Although it did bring the line down where I want it. It also stacked the numbers portion on top of each other, which for me is like hopping from one frying pan into another. But thanks you for responding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print('\n', even_count, ' even numbers total to ', even_sum, sep='')
```

should do it. Just manually put in a new line somewhere

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example of the problem:

```
>>> def test1():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("foo", end=" ")
    print("bar")


>>> test1()
foo foo foo bar # still using end=" " from inside the loop
```

A minimal example of one solution:

```
>>> def test2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("foo", end=" ")
    print() # empty print to get the default end="\n" back
    print("bar")


>>> test2()
foo foo foo 
bar
```

This empty `print` can sit anywhere between the end of the `for` loop in which you `print` the individual numbers and `print(even_count, ...`, for example:

```
...
        odd_sum += number

print()
print(even_count, 'even numbers total to', even_sum)
```

Comment: this does not put the output on separate lines

Comment: @PadraicCunningham don't follow, sorry; this approach *will* split up `90 75 60 45 30 3 even numbers total to 180` onto two separate lines.

Comment: @jonsharpe, it puts it all on one line, I mean using `print(even_count,'even numbers total to',even_sum,end=" ")` unless I am misunderstanding you

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah, perhaps it isn't clear - the `print()` sits between  the end of the `for` loop and `print(even_count, ...`.

Comment: @johnsharpe, so no need for `end = " "`, sorry I did not follow.

Answer (score 0):

### [Output for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb3vC.png)

def main():

```
x = int(input('Number of high range?: '))
y = int(input('Number of low range?: '))
z = int(input('Multiple to find?: '))
print("The numbers are as follows:")
show_multiples(x,y,z)
```

def show_multiples(x,y,z):

```
for a in range(x,y,-1):

    if a % z == 0:
        
        print (a,end=' ')
        even_count = 0
        even_sum = 0
        odd_count = 0
        odd_sum = 0
for num in range(x,y,-1):
    if num % z == 0 and num % 2 == 0:
        even_count += 1
        even_sum += num
        
for number in range(x,y,-1):
    if number % z == 0 and number % 2 == 1:
        odd_count += 1
        odd_sum += number
print(' ')
print(even_count,'even numbers total to',even_sum)
print(odd_count,'odd numbers total to',odd_sum)
```

main()